# javascript cannot read property undefined of undefined

Tags: for-loop, multidimensional-array, click

I need help and quick since this project is for this wednesday and i dont know what its wrong with my code and its screwing everything.

This is supposed to be a battleships game

the click handler keeps screwing me over and i hope you can help me`

```
    this.Handler = function (getRow, getColumn) {
        var myId = "#grid_" + getRow + "_" + getColumn;

    if (this.GridArray[getRow][getColumn] == 0) {
        $(myId).removeClass('grid');
        $(myId).addClass('gridMiss');

        this.bullets--;
    }
    else if (this.GridArray[getRow][getColumn] == 1) {
        $(myId).removeClass('grid');
        $(myId).addClass('gridHit');
        explosion.pause();
        explosion.play();

        Ships.isHit(getRow, getColumn);
        this.ShipStatus();

        this.bullets--;
        this.bulletStatus();

        //call the function that keep track of the hits of the ships
    }
}

this.ClickHandler = function () {
    refOutside = this
    $('.grid').click(function (eventData) {
        var getRow = $(this).attr('data-Row');
        var getColumn = $(this).attr('data-Column');

        refOutside.Handler(getRow, getColumn);
    });
}
```

}

And in here i have the creation of the array

```
this.CreateEmptyGrid = function () {

    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        this.GridArray[i] = [];
        for (j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++) {
            this.GridArray[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please explain what exactly goes wrong, and include any relevant information; such as what framework you are using or what error messages you are getting.

Comment: "keeps screwing me over" is not a technical description of the problem. Describe the behavior you're getting. Describe the behavior you want.